# Sequelize Mock trying to go into Database connection

Tags: sequelize.js

We are using sequelize mock library to mock database connection, we have done proxy require to mock models, but seems to be trying to make connection to actual database.

Any setting we need to do to mock sequelize library using sequelize library.

Ideally it should completely ignore database.

Comment: Adding some source code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1937#issuecomment-462543444

> You have `a.js`, requiring `b.js`, and `c.js`. Meanwhile `c.js` will also require `b.js`. And you are mocking `b.js`. So proxyquire would mock **only** the `b.js` required from `a.js`.

You probably have one Javascript file requiring sequelize library instead of sequelize-mock.

> `jest.mock` will mock **any** `b.js`, required from any place.

The example below, from 
https://github.com/kvr2277/sequelize-mock-jest/blob/master/src/test/UserDAO.spec.js, shows how to use jest and sequelize-mock:

```
let UserDAO = require('../main/daos/UserDAO');

jest.mock('../main/models/USER', () => () => {
  const SequelizeMock = require("sequelize-mock");
  const dbMock = new SequelizeMock();
  return dbMock.define('user',  {
    userId: 2,
    emailId: 'xyz@abc.com',
    firstName: 'good',
    lastName: 'day',
    creTs: "2019-01-01 13:30:31",
    creUserId: 'dummy'
  })
});


describe("Test Sequelize Mocking", () => {  
  it("Should get value from mock", async () => {
    const user = await UserDAO.getOneUser();
    expect(user.firstName).toEqual('good');
  })
})
```